# Как остановить setInterval в данном случае?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval, interval

Мне нужно остановить данный `setInterval` через 3 секунды.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать ?

```js
var slotGame = function() {
    image.src=imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
    image2.src=imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
    image3.src=imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
    image4.src=imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
    image5.src=imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
    image6.src=imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
    image7.src=imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
    image8.src=imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
    image9.src=imgs[Math.floor(Math.random()*imgs.length)];
}

    button.onclick = function() {
        setInterval(slotGame, 120);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button.onclick = function() {
  const interval = setInterval(slotGame, 120);
  setTimeout(()=> clearInterval(interval),3000);
};
```

```js
button.onclick = function() {
  const interval = setInterval(() => console.log('...'), 1000);
  setTimeout(()=> clearInterval(interval),3000);
};
```

```html
<button id="button">Click</button>
```